# Is it possible to start iOS app clips with custom urls?

Tags: ios, ios14

Is it possible to start [iOS App Clips](https://developer.apple.com/app-clips/) with custom urls? I do not want my customers to enter information multiple times.

Comment: What do you mean by custom urls? Do you mean custom scheme urls (e.g. my app://link?key=val) or an HTTPS url?

Comment: @pietrorea
I would like to set metrics in the url like app://link.insta=benerlosan035... so my customer does not need to enter his Instagram Account again : )

Comment: I think you can do as for app invocation from url (: [](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/configuring_your_app_clip_s_launch_experience)) : do something like my-app-scheme://appclip&insta=user-Instagram-name and then handle the url in your app

Comment: custom scheme urls scheme for app clip is not working for me, did it work for you ?